# Is bintray repository available for free?

Tags: maven, bintray, maven-dependency

I searched for:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
  <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
  <version>11.2.0.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And found it at [this site](https://www.versioneye.com/java/com.oracle:ojdbc6/11.2.0.2.0). It provides 2 links, one to [mvnsearch](http://www.mvnsearch.org/maven2/com/oracle/ojdbc6/) and second for [bintray](http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/oracle/ojdbc6). `mvnsearch` does not work while `bintray` can be opened without any authentication process.  It doesn't prompt for a username or password. So does bintray provide this dependency for free or there will be a problem when jar downloaded several times?

Comment: Add comment please after downvoting. May be I delete question by mysefl, but without comments I do not knot what is wrong.

Comment: By the way it is really unclear, in main page they told about paying access, but provide dependencies in open way.

Comment: I down voted because the links are broken. But I understand the essence of the question. You are worried that someday the maven dependency will fail to download in the future.

Answer (score 5):

The link you have supplied is to [JCenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter), which is an open source free maven repository built on top of JFrog Bintray.  JFrog Bintray provides some free services to open-source users.  Bottom line, the link is free.

*Disclaimer: I am with JFrog.*

Comment: Looks strange, due to oracle is proprioritary library, why they provide open access to it?

Comment: The link is free to download, however usage is subject to licence.

Comment: These scattered maven links here and there that is sprinkled all around is very confusing. Who can tell if they are true? If the uploader of this frogs deletes the uploads, then the dependency coordinates will break. Is oracle the owner of these frogs?